# Do Toolbars have to be at bottom?

Tags: ios, toolbar

In Apple's [iOS Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/ui-bars/toolbars/) it says:

> "A toolbar appears at the bottom of an app screen and contains buttons
>   for performing actions relevant to the current view or content within
>   it. "

I've implemented a `UIPickerView` with a toolbar sitting on top of it that looks like this:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Is it ok to do this even though the toolbar doesn't sit on the bottom or is Apple going to have problems with that? Thanks.

Comment: If the appearance and behavior isn't the platform standard, it should be carefully considered before implementing it. If all other apps follow the guidelines you've quoted, users expect apps to appear that way. What difference does it make if Apple is going to have problems with it if all the users who use it are? (And as an opinion, your UI is incorrect, whether it's on Apple, Android, or Windows. The options to confirm or cancel come *after* the option selection or performing an action, not before. That means below, not above. People read from top to bottom.)

Comment: I think the UI makes sense. Thanks for your input though.

Comment: OK. Make the next choice before reading any further, though: Yes or No......No, don't cheat and read ahead - answer first. The question: Will users agree with the option to choose Cancel or Done *before they've had a chance to read what they're opting to cancel or be done with*? *Chicken or egg?* No, the question isn't which came first; it's *which one do you more often eat for breakfast?*. Logic says you confirm a choice *after you have a choice to make*, not before. I'd delete your app from any device because the UI tells me you don't know what you're doing. Guidelines exist for a reason.

Comment: If they press `done` before they've selected their option they can just click on the button that made this picker show up in the first place, its not the end of the world.

Comment: You're not listening. They need to be offered a choice **before** they can choose to accept it or cancel, not **after**. This is simple common sense. It's not about whether it's the end of the world; it's about not confusing your users by designing a UI that doesn't make sense. But it's your app. You can choose to make it usable or useless; you've clearly made up your mind already which way you want to go. Good luck.

Comment: Look up "done button UIPickerView" and see how many people have done it. [Actually, here I've done it for you](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&rlz=1C5CHFA_enUS725US725&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=uipicker+done+button)

Comment: Why do you even need a toolbar here? It looks to me like an ordinary view containing a Cancel button and a Done button.

Comment: Your search is irrelevant. Do a search for *Stupid UIs that offer a Cancel or Done button before displaying what they're going to be cancelling first*. I'm done here. You're clearly lacking in common sense and logic.  I've wasted enough time trying to save you from your own inability to think. Your users will take care of the rest. Good luck with your application.

Comment: @KenWhite just searched it, absolutely nothing relevant, great job adding to the discussion.

Comment: You're right. It had no results. Why? Because stupid user interfaces like that don't exist, because everyone else is smart enough to know you don't ask a user to make a choice before telling them what they're choosing. But good luck for you - you'll be the only result of that search after you publish your app. Good for you!

Answer (score -1):

No, you can use it neatly.

In storyboard:

[image]

There you can add constraints to it.

[image]

The result of toolbar:

[image]

---

**Update**

If you find this untrue statement of document, you can report it to Apple from there:

View Bug Reporter

https://bugreport.apple.com

Comment: This doesn't answer my question, I'm not asking how to do it, I'm asking if Apple has a problem with it.

Comment: This  has nothing to do with the question asked. It's clear from the image in the question that the poster has already done this, so explaining how to do so is useless.

Comment: @MarksCode, If you ask if the Apple has a problem with its document, I will say yes. No body can do a thing without a mistake. You should not attention    this type issue, we just feel relieved to use.

Comment: @aircraft  I can't understand what you're trying to say, can you clarify?